# codeigniter controller shows 500 on fatcow server

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello there i have a php code that used codeigniter. It running on localhost perfectly. After i upload it to fatcow server it fails. 
But not entirely just 1 controller. There are four controllers(pages, posts, trainings, users) every controller working fine except posts. When i try to load functions of posts controller it's showing 500 error message.

I tried to rename posts controller to reports and its model to report also renamed views but it's not solving my problem

```
current file names: 
model: report.php
controller: reports.php
view: report/index.php, report/view.php
```

---

************** EDIT HERE IS reports.php **************

---

```
class Reports extends MY_Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function index() {
    //Pagination Configuration
    $this->custom_config["total_rows"] = $this->report->record_count($tag);
    $this->custom_config["per_page"] = 5;
    $choice = $this->custom_config["total_rows"] / $this->custom_config["per_page"];
    $this->custom_config["num_links"] = round($choice);
    $this->pagination->initialize($this->custom_config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment($this->custom_config["uri_segment"])) ? $this->uri->segment($this->custom_config["uri_segment"]) : 0;

    $data['tags'] = explode(',', $this->report->tags()['tags']);
    $data['tags'] = array_unique($data['tags']);
    $data['reports'] = $this->report->get($this->custom_config["per_page"], $page);
    $this->load->view('template/head');
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('reports/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer', $this->footer);
  }

  public function tag($tag = FALSE) {
    $tag = ($tag !== FALSE) ? urldecode($tag) : $tag;

    //Pagination Configuration
    $this->custom_config["total_rows"] = $this->report->record_count($tag);
    $this->custom_config["per_page"] = 5;
    $choice = $this->custom_config["total_rows"] / $this->custom_config["per_page"];
    $this->custom_config["num_links"] = round($choice);
    $this->pagination->initialize($this->custom_config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment($this->custom_config["uri_segment"])) ? $this->uri->segment($this->custom_config["uri_segment"]) : 0;

    $data['tags'] = explode(',', $this->report->tags()['tags']);
    $data['tags'] = array_unique($data['tags']);
    $data['reports'] = $this->report->get($this->custom_config["per_page"], $page, FALSE, $tag);
    $this->load->view('template/head');
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('reports/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer', $this->footer);

  }

  public function view($slug) {
    $data['tags'] = explode(',', $this->report->tags()['tags']);
    $data['tags'] = array_unique($data['tags']);
    $data['report'] = $this->report->get(1, 0, $slug);
    if(empty($data['report'])) {
      show_404();
    } else {
      $this->load->view('template/head');
      $this->load->view('template/header');
      $this->load->view('reports/view', $data);
      $this->load->view('template/footer', $this->footer);
    }
  }
}
```

---

********** EDIT HERE IS report.php (model) ***********

---

```
class Report extends CI_Model {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function record_count($tag = FALSE) {
    $this->db->from('categories');
    $this->db->join('contents','categories.id = contents.category_id');
    $this->db->where('categories.name', 'post');
    if ($tag !== FALSE) {
      $this->db->like('status', $tag);
    }
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
  }

  function get($limit, $start, $slug = FALSE, $tag = FALSE) {
    if($this->session->userdata('language') == 'english') {
      $this->db->select('slug, status, name_en as name, content_en as content, started_on, ended_on, admins.name as author');
    } else {
      $this->db->select('slug, status, contents.name, content, started_on, ended_on, admins.name as author');
    }
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->from('categories');
    $this->db->join('contents','categories.id = contents.category_id');
    $this->db->join('admins','admins.id = contents.admin_id');
    $this->db->where('categories.name', 'post');
    $this->db->order_by("contents.id", "desc");
    if ($tag !== FALSE) {
      $this->db->like('status', $tag);
    }
    if ($slug !== FALSE) {
      $this->db->where('slug', $slug);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->row_array();
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
  }

  function get_footer() {
    if($this->session->userdata('language') == 'english') {
      $this->db->select('slug, name_en as name');
    }
    $this->db->from('categories');
    $this->db->join('contents','categories.id = contents.category_id');
    $this->db->where('categories.name', 'post');
    $this->db->order_by("contents.id", "desc");
    $this->db->limit(2);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
  }

  function tags() {
    $this->db->select('group_concat(status) as tags');
    $this->db->from('categories');
    $this->db->join('contents','categories.id = contents.category_id');
    $this->db->where('categories.name', 'post');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
  }
}
```

Comment: Without any code or server logs to look at, it's practically impossible to know why you'd be receiving this error.

Comment: I added reports.php (reports controller) code. I can't find error log on fatcow. There is not useful information on access log. It shows only which file when loaded. Seems no error on there.

Comment: If your code works locally but fails on your host, it has to be something to do with the configuration of the remote server - maybe the PHP.ini, maybe the .htaccess, maybe permissions, maybe even the PHP version - there's too many potential causes. I think you're going to have to find a way to view the server logs to narrow down what the cause is.

Comment: i just checked error log. But it's totally empty.
1. I also tried access without .htaccess it gives same result.
2. Gave 777 on controller it is same.
3. checked versions. codeigniter requires 5.2 <. Fat cow has 5.3

not yet check php.ini.

Comment: One additional thing controller seems works fine i commented all function body. And it work fine. After that i commented only model connections. It still works which means there is an problem with model. Inserted model code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first of all it was my fault and thanks to [Michael O'Brien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2272595/michael-obrien). 
And posting a solution. Hoping it might helps someone in someday.

Problem was with mysql version. I used concat_group on sql script, which only works greater than mysql 5.6. Fatcow mysql version was 5.5. I replaced group_concat with following and it works.

```
function tags() {
    $this->db->select('status as tag');
    $this->db->from('categories');
    $this->db->join('contents','categories.id = contents.category_id');
    $this->db->where('categories.name', 'post');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}


$temp = '';
$data['tags'] = $this->mpost->tags();
foreach ($data['tags'] as $row) {
    $temp .= $row['tag'].",";
}
$data['tags'] = explode(',', $temp);
$data['tags'] = array_unique($data['tags']);
```